# Did Mr. Incredible kill these henchmen?

Tags: the-incredibles

There was a scene after the Parr family escapes imprisonment with Violet's help, near the end of the movie, in which we see a van full of bad guys. They celebrate while Syndrome impersonates a Super and causes havoc, but not long afterward Mr. Incredible ruins the party by entering that van and closing the door, so viewers can't see what happens inside.

When I was a kid, I thought that he simply knocked them out, but now I remember that he killed some other bad guys throughout the movie. I don't mind superheroes killing their enemies, but I'm curious as to the implication behind that particular scene. Word of god would be appreciated, but I doubt there is one.

Did Mr. Incredible actually kill those henchmen?

Comment: Welcome to SFF!  I always just assumed he knocked them out; I don't remember him killing anyone in that movie.

Comment: Oh ye of little faith. You should change your name to DoubtingNotTemporarilyHere

Answer (score 11):

According to [the script](https://web.archive.org/web/20121021050834/http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/The-Incredibles.pdf) he simply rendered them ***[unconscious](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/punch+out)*** (with his fists).

> OUTSIDE THE MOBILE UNIT
>
> The vehicle ROCKS as **Bob quickly punches out the guards within**. In moments Bob emerges, whistles to his family that the coast is clear.